# How do I get rid of the blank space on top of my app?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am unsure if the blank space is caused by my `NavigationView` or the `ZStack` containing the gradient. How would I go about removing the space above so I can centre my content?

```
NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                VStack(spacing: 50) {
                    Text("Pick a party!")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .offset(y:0)
                            
                    NavigationLink(destination: DemsView()) {
                        FlagImage(image: "Democrat")
                            .offset(y:0)
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: GOPView()) {
                        FlagImage(image: "Republican")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to iOS development, and I've heard about angry people not putting solutions if their problem was solved, so here it is:

```
NavigationView {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red]),    startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Just add spacing on the VStack if you need to space out the icons.